# Unity3D in game recording algorithm

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-recording

I wonder how does the recording algorithm work.

My initial thought is getting texture from **LateUpdate()** every frame.

Supposed my target frame rate of video is 30fps, if my game runs at 60fps, and I only captured the first 30fps, then the problem is I will lose some frames.

If my game runs at 20fps, I dont have enough frames for 30fps video, so should I copy 10 times of the 20th frame?

Is there an tutorial about to start? I searched online but hardly can find a related good tutorial.

Comment: "how does the recording algorithm work." Which algorithm are you referring to? Are you trying to write your own video recording feature from scratch in to your game? If so, [have you considered a free plugin from the asset store instead](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/75653)?

Comment: Yeah, I want to understand the algorithm instead of using a free one..

Comment: If the game isn't running at the same frame rate as the video, the correct answer is: drop or duplicate frames *at an even distribution.* That is, if the game is running at 60 fps and you're recording at 30, *drop **every other** frame.*  Don't record the first 30 and discard the second 30, that's dumb.  See [page two](http://www.digitalcinemasociety.org/downloads/FrameRateConversionSimplified-N.pdf)

Comment: gottcha, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want fixed capturing frame rate, you can user `FixedUpdate()`. You can set `FixedDeltaTime`value to dermine capturing framerate:

```
[Range(1,60)]
public int capturingFrameRate = 30;

void aStart()
{
    Time.fixedDeltaTime = 1 / capturingFrameRate;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //capture frame
}
```

Reference : [FixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

hope this helps

Comment: my question is more like : if my game runs at 60fps, and I only captured the first 30fps, then the problem is I will lose some frames.

If my game runs at 20fps, I dont have enough frames for 30fps video, so should I copy 10 times of the 20th frame?